# When using PInvoke, when should you use class and when struct when asked to input a pointer to a NAME struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, pinvoke

Sorry if the question is a bit off. When using PInvoke in C#, some functions require structs which will be filled with data but, from what I have seen some functions only work when said struct, in C#, is written as a class, so instead of `public struct StructName` you would do `public class StructName`.

If you don't get what I mean, you can try to run this code and see what happens

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern void GetSystemInfo([In, Out] SystemInfoStruct lpSystemInfo);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern void GetSystemInfo([In, Out] SystemInfoClass lpSystemInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SystemInfoStruct
{
    public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
    private ushort wReserved;
    public uint dwPageSize;
    public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
    public IntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
    public uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
    private uint dwProcessorType;
    public uint dwAllocationGranularity;
    public ushort wProcessorLevel;
    public ushort wProcessorRevision;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SystemInfoClass
{
    public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
    private ushort wReserved;
    public uint dwPageSize;
    public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
    public IntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
    public uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
    private uint dwProcessorType;
    public uint dwAllocationGranularity;
    public ushort wProcessorLevel;
    public ushort wProcessorRevision;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //SystemInfoClass infoClass = new SystemInfoClass();
        //GetSystemInfo(infoClass);

        //SystemInfoStruct infoStruct = new SystemInfoStruct();
        //GetSystemInfo(infoStruct);
    }
}
```

At least for me, using a struct failed and returned with a r/w access denied error, on the other hand, using a class worked.
So, the question is, when should you use structs and when should you use classes for PInvoke functions, or should you always use classes?
Who knows, maybe I am overlooking something important.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with C or C++?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Also, note that including multiple language tags in a single question is not popular; people tend to down-vote such questions.  Your code appears to be C#; and answer in C wouldn't help you, and neither would an answer in C++ — they're 3 radically different languages.  Choose one language tag only.

Comment: Was the function you called was managed or unmanaged?

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean? `GetSystemInfo` is unmanaged.

Comment: Using a struct is the normal and recommended way, but you have to match the native function declaration.  From the MSDN docs "A pointer to a SYSTEM_INFO structure that receives the information".  Generating a pointer to the struct requires `out` in the [DllImport] declaration.  When you declare it as a class, a reference type, then you automatically get the pointer and don't use `out`.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, I see. Didn't know that, thanks for explaining it to me. :)

Comment: Get SystemInfo is part of Kernal32.dll.  See pinvoke : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetSystemInfo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should use whatever https://pinvoke.net/ says that you should use. If it says that it needs to be invoked with a `struct`, pass a `struct`.  If it says that it needs to be invoked with a `class`, pass a `class`.

Now, if you want to live life dangerously, you can try to interchange `class` and `struct`, but be aware of the fact that passing a `class` is not exactly equivalent to passing a `struct`; instead, it is equivalent to passing a `struct` by `ref`.

Comment: @HansPassant the question had been unanswered for more than half an hour before I provided the OP with an answer that solves his problem.  I did so from memory, while I have not used .Net in something like 6 years. Feel free to edit my answer to correct my mistakes.